# SQLite syntax REPLACE + WHERE

Tags: sqlite

What am I doing wrong in the following code?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chunks(x Integer(20) NOT NULL, y Integer(20) NOT NULL, 
            height Integer(20) NOT NULL, version Timestamp default (strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIME)), 
            datas Text NOT NULL);
REPLACE INTO chunks VALUES(0,0,0,NULL,'Bla') WHERE x IS 0 AND y IS 0 AND height IS 0;
```

Comment: Still the same result "Error: near "WHERE": syntax error"

Comment: Replace `Integer(20)` with `INTEGER` and  `IS` with `=`

Comment: That SQL statement does not make sense. Describe what do you want to do.

Comment: @CL. oh hm... my thought was that i need to replace `version` and `datas` but just if a row with exactly `x`, `y `,`height` exists otherwise create it. Maybe i am just to tierd to see my fail here but as far as i think , if i use `INSERT` it will just add a new row even if that coorinates(x,y,height) already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE requires the table to have a UNIQUE constraint on the columns you want to search, and always deletes the old row if it finds one.

A better idea is to explicitly check whether the row exists:

```py
cursor.execute("UPDATE chunks SET ... WHERE x = ? AND y = ? AND height = ?",
               [0, 0, 0])
if cursor.rowcount == 0:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO chunks ...")
```